# setLayoutParams vs addView for adding a new view

Tags: android, android-layout, layoutparams

What is the difference between using setLayoutParams and supplying the parameters to addView?

I understand that addView only works when adding the view for the first time.
I found two ways of apparently doing the same thing:

```
tv.setLayoutParams(params);
layout.addView(tv)
```

vs

```
layout.addView(tv, params)
```

Are they equivalent?
If not what are the differences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are they equivalent?

Yes, the first method does an extra check to see if the `View` which is being added has `LayoutParams` set on it(and generate some `LayoutParams` if they don't exist). You could choose either one(I would pick the second method call).